# Can't pass model data in templates django

Tags: python, django

I want to pass data from 'About' model to html template, but I can't figure out what is going wrong.. as I am new to Django. I gave lot of time to it.. but it still remains the same:

```
from django.db import models


class About(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pics')
    desc  = models.TextField()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import About

def index(request):
    abt = About.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home/index.html',{abt:'abt'})
```

html

```
      <img src="{{abt.image}" alt="profile photo"> 

      <p>{{abt.desc}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{abt:'abt'}`

No, it's other way around.

`{'abt':abt}`

Label on the left, data on the right.

If you want to get a single instance you can use `first` method

```
    <p>{{abt.first.desc}}</p>
```

or in the similar way, provide only the first object

```
return render(request,'home/index.html',{'abt': abt.first()})
```

Comment: Please update your code to what you have right now and try to put `{{ abt | pprint }}` in your template.

Comment: hi i replaced {{abt.desc}}with {{ abt | pprint }} and i got this in my template <QuerySet [<About: About object (1)>]>

Comment: also i am trying to fetch a single instance of object (single row from database table) that is why i did not used for loop

Comment: hi this is working now.. but still image is not there..  <img src="{{abt.image.urls}" alt="profile photo"> ... i tried {{abt.image}}  too